# Unity 2D: Facing direction without moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a Pokémon game in unity2d. I manage to make the grid movement but I don't have a clue on how face the direction without moving (staying in the same place and when A or W or S or D is pressed once just facing the direction without moving).

That's what I have so far:

```
[SerializeField]
float walkingVelocity = 2;
[SerializeField]
float runingVelocity = 4;

Vector3 p;                                // For movement
Animator anim;

Vector2 input;
float actualSpeed = 0;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    p = transform.position;          // Take the initial position
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    actualSpeed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ? walkingVelocity : runingVelocity;

    if (input != Vector2.zero && p == transform.position)
    {

        //CalcularHierbaAlta();
        if (Mathf.Abs(input.x) > Mathf.Abs(input.y))
        {
            if (input.x > 0)
            {
                //direccion = Direccion.Este;
                //PuedeMoverse = CalcularFrente();
                p += Vector3.right;
                anim.SetFloat("input_x", input.x);
                anim.SetFloat("input_y", input.y);
                anim.SetBool("isMoving", true);
            }
            else
            {
                p -= Vector3.right;
                anim.SetFloat("input_x", input.x);
                anim.SetFloat("input_y", input.y);
                anim.SetBool("isMoving", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (input.y > 0)
            {
                p += Vector3.up;
                anim.SetFloat("input_x", input.x);
                anim.SetFloat("input_y", input.y);
                anim.SetBool("isMoving", true);
            }
            else
            {
                p -= Vector3.up;
                anim.SetFloat("input_x", input.x);
                anim.SetFloat("input_y", input.y);
                anim.SetBool("isMoving", true);
            }
        }
    }else if (input == Vector2.zero)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isMoving", false);
    }
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, p, actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are already facing a direction. If not, then rotate your object. If you are already facing the direction that the key press would move you in, then move the player/object.

Comment: Oh my god, it was so obvious! I have not tried it yet but it makes a lot of sense. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

i had the exact same problem and this is how i managed to do it ;)
the line

```
if (pressWalkTime >= 8) {
```

can be used to determine how many frames the button can be pressed for, before start moving in the direction.

```
    if (horizontal != 0 || vertical != 0) {
        if (pressWalkTime != 0 || !direction.Equals (new Vector2 (horizontal, vertical))) {
            pressWalkTime++;

            if (pressWalkTime >= 8) {
                pressWalkTime = 0;
            }   
        } else {
            pressWalkTime = 0;
        }   

        direction = new Vector2 (horizontal, vertical);

        if (pressWalkTime == 0 && base.AttemptMove (horizontal, vertical)) {
            position += new Vector2 (horizontal, vertical);
        }

        if (horizontal == 1)
            animator.Play ("Walk-Right");

        if (horizontal == -1)
            animator.Play ("Walk-Left");

        if (vertical == 1)
            animator.Play ("Walk-Up");

        if (vertical == -1)
            animator.Play ("Walk-Down");

    } else
        pressWalkTime = 0;
}
```

you also should notice that this could does not handle turns. that means that if you are already walking in a direction and then turn in another one you have to wait 8 frames again to start moving. this problem will be solved tommorow, but i'm sure that you can do it on your own ;)

pressWalkTime is an attribute of the class this logic is written in. and is initialized with 0.

Comment: oh btw the method base.AttemptMove just checks wether the field you want to enter is accessable. but i guess thats obvios